# Rectangle makes Texture2D invisible

Tags: c#, xna

In the game I'm currently working on I have a play button which have a `Vector2`, a `Rectangle`, and a `Texture2D`. But somehow when I run the game the play button is invisible, but it still reacts to mouse collision/detection.
This is my code:

```
    Texture2D buttonPlay;
    Rectangle buttonPlayRect;
    Vector2 buttonPlayPos;

    Point mousePosition;

    int resolutionX = ScreenManager.GraphicsDeviceMgr.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
    int resolutionY = ScreenManager.GraphicsDeviceMgr.PreferredBackBufferHeight;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        buttonPlayPos = new Vector2(resolutionX / 2 - 64, resolutionY / 2 - 64);
    }

    public override void LoadAssets()
    {
       buttonOptionsPos = new Vector2(resolutionX / 2 - 64, resolutionY / 2);

       backgroundTile = ScreenManager.ContentMgr.Load<Texture2D>("Menu/background");
       buttonOptions = ScreenManager.ContentMgr.Load<Texture2D>("Menu/optionsButton");
       buttonPlay = ScreenManager.ContentMgr.Load<Texture2D>("Menu/playButton");

       buttonPlayRect = new Rectangle((int)buttonPlayPos.X, (int)buttonPlayPos.Y, buttonPlay.Width, buttonPlay.Height);

        base.LoadAssets();
    }

    public override void Update(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();
        mousePosition = new Point(mState.X, mState.Y);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                ScreenManager.Sprites.Draw(backgroundTile, new Vector2(tileWidth * x, tileHeight * y), Color.White);
            }
        }

        ScreenManager.Sprites.Draw(buttonPlay, buttonPlayPos, buttonPlayRect, Color.White);
        ScreenManager.Sprites.Draw(buttonOptions, buttonOptionsPos, Color.White);

        if (buttonPlayRect.Contains(mousePosition))
        {

        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

I've had this problem for a while with other projects aswell, what makes the `Texture2D` not appear? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `buttonOptions` show?

Comment: Yes, it does but i don't draw it with the `buttonOptionsRect`.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw something I suggest you to use only the `Vector2 position` or the `destinationRectangle` of the `SpriteBatch.Draw`, sometimes it behaves unexpectedly.
What's more, there's no reason to set a position and use it to declare a rectangle if you pass both them as parameters.

And as a suggestion, you should check `buttonPlayRect.Contains(mousePosition)` in your `Update` method, `Draw` should only manage the drawing of your game, not the logic.

**UPDATE**

If you need to change the postion of your buttons depending on the current resolution, you can draw them declaring the position in every `Draw` cycle

```
new Vector2(resolutionX / 2 - 64, resolutionY / 2 - 64);
```

or you can add an event handler in this way:

Add this in your `Initialize` method:

```
Game.Window.ClientSizeChanged += Window_ClientSizeChanged;
```

then create the `Window_ClientSizeChanged` method with something like this:

```
private void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonPlayPos = new Vector2(resolutionX / 2 - 64, resolutionY / 2 - 64);
    buttonPlayRect = new Rectangle((int)buttonPlayPos.X, (int)buttonPlayPos.Y, buttonPlay.Width, buttonPlay.Height);
}
```

Of course `resolutionX` and `resolutionY` have to be the updated values.

Comment: Thanks! But now, my resolutionX and resolutionY doesn't change the position of the button at all, should i declare it in another way, because i want them to be in middle of the screen no matter what resolution :/

Comment: And was them with the previous code? You can add an event handler to `Game.Window.ClientSizeChanged` and change the position of your buttons.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand really, since i'm in the beginner state of XNA D:

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but Game.Window doesnt exist, i only get "Equals" and "ReferenceEquals", and i could not Resolve it by using a Library :/

Comment: With `Game` I mean the parameter, not the class, `Game` is a parameter that exists only in classes that inherits from `GameComponent` or in the base class `Game1`.